# How to check status of connection with nmcli

Tags: linux, bash

Please let me know how to check the current status of a connection with ID `HMA` using `nmcli` on Linux.

I wrote this simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for((i=1, $i<=10;i++)); do
 {
 echo "nr.:$i"
 nmcli con up id HMA
 sleep 15
 nmcli con down id HMA
}
```

Unfortunately, sometimes this error occurs:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: unknown reason.
Warning: Connection not active
```

Is there any way to check the status and to reestablish the connection in the failure case?

I know there is no try-catch in bash but I need something similar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to debug, change to `nmcli con X id HMA; echo status=$?` If you don't get `status=0`, then you can script a retry. Let us know. Good luck.

Comment: That's right. you can also save the `$?` to a variable/local variable and check if it's equal to 0

Comment: I always get an exit code of 0, even when the nmcli returns errors like "Connection activation failed: (53)"... Why?

Comment: What your script currently does is activating and deactivating a connection. To get the status of a connection using `nmcli`, check out [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441969/use-nmcli-to-display-the-status-of-a-connection/534099#534099).